# Search multiple words while ignoring the word order in Fuse (Javascript fuzzy search)

Tags: javascript, search, fuse

how can i match multiple words in [fuse](https://github.com/krisk/Fuse) while ignoring anything in between and also ignoring the word-order?

for the following example (pseudo-code) the algorithm should match the all items in the `possibleResults`-array for the search-term `team lead`.

```
const options = {}
const possibleResults = ['lead', 'team lead', 'lead of software development team']
const fuse = new Fuse(possibleResults, options)
fuse.search('team lead')
```

i've tried it with the following options:

```
{
threshold: 0, // the lower the more exact
ignoreLocation: true, // ignores how "far" result is
findAllMatches: true,
};
```

but without success. as far as i know Fuse now always sets `tokenize: true` per default. so that's not helping ...

Answer (score 1):

one solution i'll leave here just in case someone else stumbles across the same issue is:

```
const options = {useExtendedSearch: true}    
const adaptedSearchTerm = 'team lead'.split(' ').reduce((previousValue, currentValue) => previousValue + ` '${currentValue}`, '');
fuse.search(adaptedSearchTerm)
```

which makes use of the extended-search feature of fuse by adding  `'` in front of every splitted search-term.

Comment: Good one. This looks cleaner:
'team lead'.split(' ').map(word => `'${word}`).join(' ')